# f:validateDoubleRange localization

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have poblem with localized message for validation error in the f:validateDoubleRange

```
<h:inputText id="inputId" required="true"
        value="#{bean.value}">
     <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="0"/>
</h:inputText>
```

I try to localize error message in my registered properties file this way:

```
javax.faces.converter.DoubleConverter.DOUBLE_detail=Some new message
```

but the message remains the same like in the *javax/faces/Messages.properties*

```
javax.faces.converter.DoubleConverter.DOUBLE_detail={2}: ''{0}'' must be a number between 4.9E-324 and 1.7976931348623157E308  Example: {1}
```

Maybe do I trying to change no that message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, only the **summary** message will be displayed by `<h:message>` and `<h:messages>`, but you're overriding the **detail** message.

You need to override the summary message instead:

```
javax.faces.converter.DoubleConverter.DOUBLE=Some new message
```

The detail message is only displayed whenever you use

```
<h:messages showSummary="false" showDetail="true" />
```

Comment: This is strange but it works. By default the detail message is shown instead summary. I wonder why I can't override detailed message